# No module named 'backend'

Tags: python, import, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to separate my code into files. When I am trying to import any variables from another file I get the following error:

```
File ".\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from backend.Measure import Measure,MeasurementSchema,measure_schema,measures_schema
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'
```

I have 3 files:

- **app.py**

  ```
  from flask import Flask, Request, jsonify
  from backend.Measure import Measure,MeasurementSchema,measure_schema,measures_schema
  from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

  app = Flask(__name__)

  db = SQLAlchemy(app)


  @app.route('/api/measures')
  def getAllMeasurements():
      results = Measure.query.all()
      return measures_schema.jsonify(results)
  ```
- **Measure.py**

  ```
  from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
  from backend.app import app
  from backend.app import db

  ma = Marshmallow(app)

  class Measure(db.Model):
      __tablename__ = 'measurements'
      id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
      timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, auto_now_add=True)
      temperature = db.Column(db.Float)

      def __init__(self, timestamp, temperature):
          self.timestamp = timestamp
          self.temperature = temperature

  class MeasurementSchema(ma.Schema):
      class Meta:
          fields = ('id', 'timestamp', 'temperature')

  measure_schema = MeasurementSchema()
  measures_schema = MeasurementSchema(many=True)
  ```
- **db.py**

  ```
  from sqlalchemy import create_engine

  server = 'localhost'
  database = 'TESTDB'
  driver = 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
  connection_string = f'mssql+pyodbc://@{server}/{database}?trusted_connection=yes&driver={driver}'

  app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = connection_string
  app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

  engine = create_engine(connection_string)
  connection = engine.connect()
  ```

All files are in the `backend` folder as shown in the image below

[image: 1]

What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure that the "backend" module directory is in a directory that is in your python path `import sys; print(sys.path)`.

Comment: what do I need to do to add my folder to this path?

Comment: You can do `sys.path.append(<path to folder that contains backend>)`. Preferably a relative path to your folder (relative to the calling module).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to import a file from the same folder, you should do this.

In Measure.py

```
from .app import app
from .app import db
```

In app.py

```
from .Measure import Measure,MeasurementSchema,measure_schema,measures_schema
```

Comment: File ".\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .Measure import Measure,MeasurementSchema,measure_schema,measures_schema
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package